# form without submit button

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have form with some `<select>` tag and of course a submit button.
When you click on submit it display what you selected.

Can I remove the submit step?
So, I as soon the information change from my `<select>` the page will display the custom information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery's [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to prevent a submission  of a form like this:

```
$(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })

});
```

> If `preventDefault()` method is called, the default action of the
>   event will not be triggered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not so sure I get it...I'm looking for an auto-submit here if the '<selected>' is change.

Comment: Didn't get you, is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!

```
$(function() {
  $('#my-select-id').on('change', function() {

    // Here you can use the exact id...
    $('#my-form').trigger('submit');

    // Or you can use the closest()
    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');

  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing is happening look here: http://solutionford-v2.magnetis.net/vehicule-occasion/

Comment: which part of this site am I supposed to be looking at, there is a lot going on there...

Comment: Then that has something to do with your form submit action... and the data you are passing to the server. Can't help you there without any code reference. Not going to attempt to scrape through that site...